# I am using Nodemailer but I can only send emails to transporter

Tags: node.js, react-native, nodemailer

I just copied most of the example code from the nodemailer page to test it, but I can only send emails to the transporter. If i change the "to" email in mailOptions it just changes the string after to and sends it to the transporter account. I tried using gmail accounts but still same problem. There isnt much more documentation on the nodemailer site. Isnt it supposed to use the transporter account to send emails to other accounts?

all emails are going to kathleen.gleichner72@ethereal.email when i want them to go to kraig.nader71@ethereal.email

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}))

app.post('/api/form', (req, res) => {
    nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
        const htmlEmail = `
        <h3>Contact Details</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
            <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Message</h3>
        <p>${req.body.message}</p>
        `
        let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
            host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
            port: '587',
            auth: {
                user: 'kathleen.gleichner72@ethereal.email',
                pass: 'VKGKReZW5Mhwz1yKAY'
            }
        })
        let mailOptions = {
            from: 'test@testaccount.com',
            to: 'kraig.nader71@ethereal.email',
            subject: 'New Message',
            text: req.body.message,
            html: htmlEmail
        }
        transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err)
            }
            console.log('Message sent: %s', info.message )
            console.log('Message URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info) )
        })
    })
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for smtp providers.

```
host: 'smtp.ethereal.email',
port: '587',
```

This part also has to change.
As you see it uses template smtp server of nodemailer.

Comment: But even when i tried using mailtrap, it only sends email to that mailtrap account, nothing is going to the account in the "to" field

Comment: Nevermind, it was because ehereal and mailtrap dont actually send the emails, when i used gmail it worked as intended. Thanks